# Renaming & moving files based on their file path

Tags: python, rename, subdirectory, filetree

I am trying to rename files based on the treepath it is in, then move the renamed files to a specific folder (based on its name).

So, for example, I have a file in path L:\a\b\c\d\e\f\file.pdf
I want to rename "file.pdf" to "d e f"

Also, all the subfolders branch off at c so I want python to scan all the documents in the subfolders contained in folder c to be renamed according to the aforementioned pattern. I.e., L:\a\b\c\x\y\z\file.pdf, file.pdf renamed to "x y z"; L:\a\b\c\q\r\s\file.pdf, file.pdf renamed to "q r s"; etc.

Then, I want to move all those files to a new, already existing folder, based on their names. So say for example for file "d e f" I would want to move to L:a\b\1\d\f\e.

I am quite new at coding at Python and I have a few pieces of the puzzle kind of worked out but I am having a lot of trouble. Here is some of my code but I don't think it will prove very useful.

For this code, I have to drop the file into CMD with the .py file. It spits out the name I want (but with extra spaces that I don't want), it doesn't actually rename the file, and is done only with the specific file I dropped into CMD when I would rather have the code look through all of the subfolders and do it automatically. Please note that my code (specifically, lines 6-7) is specific to how the folder I want is actually named, I obfuscated the name of the tree path for confidentiality reasons and it just makes it easier to understand.

```
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv
txt = open(filename)
print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
string = "%r" % filename
print string [94:-17]
line = string [94:-17]
line = "%r" % line
for char in '\\':
line = line.replace (char, ' ')
print line
```

Doing some homework, this code will search and rename all the files in the directory I want, however it does not name it the way that I want. Again, this isn't really helpful but it is what I have.

```
import glob, os
def rename(dir, pattern, titlePattern):
for pathAndFilename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir, pattern)):
title, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pathAndFilename))
os.rename(pathAndFilename,
os.path.join(dir, titlePattern % title + ext))
rename(r'L:\a\b\c\', r'*.pdf', r'new(%s)'
```

And then for actually moving the files, I don't have any code made yet - I am pretty lost. I understand that this is a lot of work, but I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

As I found this post searching a similar solution for bash, I post an answer for people who will follow the same path :

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir extracted
for var in "$@"
do
    for f in `find sources -name "$var"`
    do
        groupname=`echo $f | cut -d'/' -f 3`
        filename=`echo ${f##*/}`
        cp "$f" extracted/"${groupname}_$filename" -v
    done
done
```